# Why is Travis CI's xenial VM finding gcc 5 and 7, but not 6?

Tags: github, gcc, travis-ci, software-distribution

I'm trying to have Travis CI build [this C project](https://github.com/eyalroz/ssb-dbgen), with [this `.travis.yml` file](https://github.com/eyalroz/ssb-dbgen/blob/master/.travis.yml). It works - almost. For some reason, building with GCC 6 fails, but not because of the project itself, but because this happens on the VM:

```
$ export MATRIX_EVAL="export CC=gcc-6"
$ export TRAVIS_COMPILER=gcc
$ export CC=gcc
$ export CC_FOR_BUILD=gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
before_install
0.00s$ eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"
0.14s$ cmake . && make
CMake Error at /usr/local/cmake-3.12.4/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:
  gcc-6.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)
```

again, this does *not* happen with GCC 5 and GCC 6

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that GCC 6 is Ubuntu Xenial's distribution's default version. So it's not available as a versioned-name binary, and there's no need to download any packages for making it available.

Just replace:

```
- os: linux
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-6
      env:
- MATRIX_EVAL="export CC=gcc-6"
```

with, say this:

```
- os: linux
      env:
- MATRIX_EVAL="echo GCC 6 will be used by default in xenial"
```

in your `.travis.yml` and you should be set.